# Comparing an already printed circuit board with Gerber files

Tags: pcb, gerber

It's my first time working with PCBs, however I have been given a task during my internship.

My task is to compare an already existed PCB hardware with its Gerber files. The Gerber files I have with me was not used originally to manufacture the board. Instead, the PCB was reverse engineered in order to get the Gerber files. This is why I have to check if it is exactly the same as the existing board before manufacturing a new board.

I would be really thankful if anyone can help me with this task. I already have some ideas like printing the Gerber view on A4 (1:1) and physically comparing. Is there an optimal way to actually perform this task?

Comment: How many layers does the PCB have? Anything more than a 2 layer board is going to be tough. If you have an inkjet printer and some transparency sheets your idea will work pretty well for a layer board as long as all of the components are removed.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't have the original Gerbers??  How can you compare your Gerbers with Gerbers that you don't have??

Comment: @Stiddily The PCB has 14 Layers. Thank you for the suggestion, I will try that out.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Yes, I don't have the original Gerber files. This is a reverse engineering problem. I have the original PCB hardware with me. The Gerber files that I have were generated from the PCB hardware. Now I have to verify it to see if it matches.

Comment: Wow, making an intern reverse-engineer a 14-layer board... sounds about right.

Comment: I'm with the others.   On a 14 layer board, you are in for a hell of a time.   Do you have the SCHEMATIC??    Many board vendors will include an ELECTRICAL TEST as part of their process.  This uses flying leads to electrically check every connection and make sure they match the schematics netlist.  So if you get a vendor to make this board, you can have them ALSO do this verification for you.   www.sunstone.com is one I know could do this.

Comment: The 'old fashioned' way is to set up an optical comparitor.  Basically you flip back & forth between the two images rapidly.  Your eye will (usually) quickly pickup any differences.   This is how Pluto and other space rocks used to be discovered.  "Blink Microscope".  In your world, you could take two perfectly sized digital photos, open both on your PC, get them exactly aligned on your screeen, and then flip back-n-forth using 'ctrl-tab'.   Any differences will become much more obvious much faster than moving your eyes back & forth.  It's a brain-stem thing more than conscious thought.

Comment: @JYelton  Yep.  I'd do the same   ;)   So would you LOL     One time, we had an intern just sit and watch our product swing back & forth for a whole semester.

Comment: Do you have access to a decent Gerber program? Decent Gerber programs can spit out a net list, typically IPC-D-356. It's helpful if have the drill files, especially if there are blind/buried vias. You'll have a net list which requires a lot a massaging (adding in reference designators, reformatting, ...), but it will be better than visually tracing out the artwork.

Answer (score 0):

Even using X-Rays, I don't think this will be possible for a 14 layer PCB without [extensive deconstruction](http://www.grandideastudio.com/pcbdt/)

Comment: Thank you for the link Scott. I know this is a difficult task, but I will learn a lot by tackling the problem and for this reason, I am happy to do it :)